# FindMinimum produces error message

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting

I'm trying to solve a logistic regression problem using *Mathematica* -- more to improve my *Mathematica* skills than to solve the problem as I have already solved it using Octave.

The problem I am experiencing is with the FindMinimum function which always returns an error no matter what I do.  I have tried it without passing the gradient function and it produces the error:

> Encountered a gradient that is effectively zero.

If I pass it the gradient function, I get the error:

> The gradient is not a vector of real numbers at {θ} = {{{0.}, {0.}, {0.}}}.

I've read through other posts with similar problems but none of recommended solutions work for me.

Below is the code from my Notebook (I hope you can copy and paste it into your own notebook).

```
data = {{34.62365962451697`, 78.0246928153624`, 0}, {30.28671076822607`, 
    43.89499752400101`, 0}, {35.84740876993872`, 72.90219802708364`, 
    0}, {60.18259938620976`, 86.30855209546826`, 1}, {79.0327360507101`, 
    75.3443764369103`, 1}, {45.08327747668339`, 56.3163717815305`, 
    0}, {61.10666453684766`, 96.51142588489624`, 1}, {75.02474556738889`, 
    46.55401354116538`, 1}, {76.09878670226257`, 87.42056971926803`, 
    1}, {84.43281996120035`, 43.53339331072109`, 1}, {95.86155507093572`, 
    38.22527805795094`, 0}, {75.01365838958247`, 30.60326323428011`, 
    0}, {82.30705337399482`, 76.48196330235604`, 1}, {69.36458875970939`, 
    97.71869196188608`, 1}, {39.53833914367223`, 76.03681085115882`, 
    0}, {53.9710521485623`, 89.20735013750205`, 1}, {69.07014406283025`, 
    52.74046973016765`, 1}, {67.94685547711617`, 46.67857410673128`, 
    0}, {70.66150955499435`, 92.92713789364831`, 1}, {76.97878372747498`, 
    47.57596364975532`, 1}, {67.37202754570876`, 42.83843832029179`, 
    0}, {89.6767757507208`, 65.79936592745237`, 1}, {50.534788289883`, 
    48.85581152764205`, 0}, {34.21206097786789`, 44.20952859866288`, 
    0}, {77.9240914545704`, 68.9723599933059`, 1}, {62.27101367004632`, 
    69.95445795447587`, 1}, {80.1901807509566`, 44.82162893218353`, 
    1}, {93.114388797442`, 38.80067033713209`, 0}, {61.83020602312595`, 
    50.25610789244621`, 0}, {38.78580379679423`, 64.99568095539578`, 0}};
```

Break data into correct matricies

```
myX = Take[data, All, 2];
myy = Take[data, All, -1];
```

Categorize rows as 0 or 1

```
posRows = Flatten[Position[myy, {1}]];
negRows = Flatten[Position[myy, {0}]];
```

Plot the dataset

```
resultsPlot =
 ListPlot[{Partition[Riffle[myX[[posRows, 1]], myX[[posRows, 2]]], 2], 
   Partition[Riffle[myX[[negRows, 1]], myX[[negRows, 2]]], 2]}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {"X", "O"}, PlotLegends -> {"Positive", "Negative"}, 
  Frame -> True]
```

Fill out the X matrix by prepending a column of 1's

```
myX = PadLeft[myX, {Length[myX], 3}, 1];
```

Create the working functions

Sigmoid function - used to ensure we have a convex function with no local minima

```
sigmoid[mat_] := 1 /(1 + E^-mat);
```

Cost function

```
cost[θ_, X_, y_] := Module[{m, hThetaX},
  m = Length[y];
  hThetaX = sigmoid[X.θ];
  Flatten[1/
     m*(-y\[Transpose].Log[hThetaX] - (1 - y)\[Transpose].Log[1 - hThetaX])]
  ]
```

Gradient function

```
grad[θ_, X_, y_] := Module[{m, hThetaX},
  m = Length[y];
  hThetaX = sigmoid[X.θ];
  Flatten[1/m*(hThetaX - y)\[Transpose].X]
  ]
```

Test the functions

```
thetaInitial = {{0}, {0}, {0}}

cost[thetaInitial, myX, myy][[1]]
grad[thetaInitial, myX, myy]
```

> ```
> Out[105]= 0.693147
>
> Out[106]= {-0.0333333, -6.63738, -6.82055}
> ```

These are the expected results.

Find the values of theta that minimise the cost

```
FindMinimum[cost[θ, myX, myy][[1]], {θ, thetaInitial}, Gradient -> grad[θ, myX, myy]]
```

> During evaluation of In[108]:= FindMinimum::nrgnum: The gradient is not a vector of real numbers at {θ} = {{{0.},{0.},{0.}}}. >>
>
> ```
> Out[108]= {0.0333333, {θ -> {{0.}, {0.}, {0.}}}}
> ```

----- EDIT -----

As per requests, I've added the full notebook below in one block to make it easier to copy and paste for testing.

```
data = {{34.62365962451697`, 78.0246928153624`, 0}, {30.28671076822607`, 
    43.89499752400101`, 0}, {35.84740876993872`, 72.90219802708364`, 
    0}, {60.18259938620976`, 86.30855209546826`, 1}, {79.0327360507101`, 
    75.3443764369103`, 1}, {45.08327747668339`, 56.3163717815305`, 
    0}, {61.10666453684766`, 96.51142588489624`, 1}, {75.02474556738889`, 
    46.55401354116538`, 1}, {76.09878670226257`, 87.42056971926803`, 
    1}, {84.43281996120035`, 43.53339331072109`, 1}, {95.86155507093572`, 
    38.22527805795094`, 0}, {75.01365838958247`, 30.60326323428011`, 
    0}, {82.30705337399482`, 76.48196330235604`, 1}, {69.36458875970939`, 
    97.71869196188608`, 1}, {39.53833914367223`, 76.03681085115882`, 
    0}, {53.9710521485623`, 89.20735013750205`, 1}, {69.07014406283025`, 
    52.74046973016765`, 1}, {67.94685547711617`, 46.67857410673128`, 
    0}, {70.66150955499435`, 92.92713789364831`, 1}, {76.97878372747498`, 
    47.57596364975532`, 1}, {67.37202754570876`, 42.83843832029179`, 
    0}, {89.6767757507208`, 65.79936592745237`, 1}, {50.534788289883`, 
    48.85581152764205`, 0}, {34.21206097786789`, 44.20952859866288`, 
    0}, {77.9240914545704`, 68.9723599933059`, 1}, {62.27101367004632`, 
    69.95445795447587`, 1}, {80.1901807509566`, 44.82162893218353`, 
    1}, {93.114388797442`, 38.80067033713209`, 0}, {61.83020602312595`, 
    50.25610789244621`, 0}, {38.78580379679423`, 64.99568095539578`, 0}};

myX = Take[data, All, 2];
myy = Take[data, All, -1];

posRows = Flatten[Position[myy, {1}]];
negRows = Flatten[Position[myy, {0}]];

resultsPlot =
 ListPlot[{Partition[Riffle[myX[[posRows, 1]], myX[[posRows, 2]]], 2], 
   Partition[Riffle[myX[[negRows, 1]], myX[[negRows, 2]]], 2]}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {"X", "O"}, PlotLegends -> {"Positive", "Negative"}, 
  Frame -> True]

myX = PadLeft[myX, {Length[myX], 3}, 1];

sigmoid[mat_] := 1 /(1 + E^-mat);

cost[\[Theta]_, X_, y_] := Module[{m, hThetaX},
  m = Length[y];
  hThetaX = sigmoid[X.\[Theta]];
  Flatten[1/
     m*(-y\[Transpose].Log[hThetaX] - (1 - y)\[Transpose].Log[1 - hThetaX])]
  ]

grad[\[Theta]_, X_, y_] := Module[{m, hThetaX},
  m = Length[y];
  hThetaX = sigmoid[X.\[Theta]];
  Flatten[1/m*(hThetaX - y)\[Transpose].X]
  ]

thetaInitial = {0, 0, 0}

cost[thetaInitial, myX, myy][[1]]
grad[thetaInitial, myX, myy]


FindMinimum[cost[\[Theta], myX, myy][[1]], {\[Theta], thetaInitial}, 
 Gradient -> grad[\[Theta], myX, myy]]
```

Comment: Testing your code requires a lot of copy/pasting.  Perhaps it would be a good idea to repeat the full code in just one code box at the end of your question

Comment: Why do you use `thetaInitial = {{0}, {0}, {0}}` rather than `thetaInitial = {0, 0, 0}`?

Comment: @belisarius Though inline annotations are useful ...

Comment: It is not necessary to differentiate between row vectors and column vectors in Mathematica.  Octave and MATLAB do not have real vectors, only matrices, so with those systems it is a *necessaity* to be aware whether something is a row vector or a column vector.  Mathematica can handle arbitrary dimensional tensors, so this is not necessary.  Treating vectors as simple vectors will save you some transpositions and flattenings here, and will improve readability.

Comment: @Szabolcs Agree. That's why I asked to _repeat_ the code at the end

Comment: Thanks for the comments team.  I've added another code block at the end of my post to make it easier for people to copy and paste to test for themselves - but this does not include the commentary which explains what is going on.  @m_goldberg et. al., the column vector representation of thetaInitial was indeed to replicate the column vector I used when implementing this in Octave however I have tried combinations of column vectors and row vectors in my Mathematica implementation but they all end up with similar errors (just more or less braces).

Comment: Theta is a vector? I dont think FindMinimum will work with a vector unknown, you need to give it the components explicitly eg {{theta1,0},{theta2,0},{theta3,0}} ..

Comment: Ok, correct myself. You CAN minimize over a vector..however you need to make sure your function doesn't evaluate for a scalar (which yours does i think).  Put theta_List in your cost function definition (first Clear[cost]).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Vector-valued variable's input syntax for `FindMinimum`

The Documentation [states](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationVariablesAndStartingConditions.html#1035657512) (emphasis mine):

> <...> since the value of the function would be meaningless unless x
>   had the correct structure, the definition is restricted to arguments
>   with that structure. For example, **if you defined the function for any
>   pattern `x_`, then evaluating with an undefined symbol `x` (which is what
>   `FindMinimum` does) gives meaningless unintended results**. It is often
>   the case that when working with functions for vector-valued variables,
>   you will have to restrict the definitions.

The main problem with your code is that your cost function and its gradient are defined for any pattern `ϴ_` and give unintended results when evaluated with undefined `ϴ`. You should restrict them to be evaluated only for the values of the vector variable `ϴ` with  correct structure.

### Solution for your particular problem

As [george2079 correctly stated](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37028/findminimum-produces-error-message#comment111190_37028) in the comments you should put `ϴ_List` in the cost function and in the gradient function and make the cost function returning a scalar (note `First` added to the definition):

```
Clear[cost, grad]
cost[θ_List, X_, y_] := First@Module[{m, hThetaX}, m = Length[y];
   hThetaX = sigmoid[X.θ];
   Flatten[1/m*(-y\[Transpose].Log[hThetaX] - (1 - y)\[Transpose].Log[1 - hThetaX])]]
grad[θ_List, X_, y_] := Module[{m, hThetaX}, m = Length[y];
  hThetaX = sigmoid[X.θ];
  Flatten[1/m*(hThetaX - y)\[Transpose].X]]
```

Now using the `"Newton"` (as well as `Gradient`-free `"PrincipalAxis"`) method everything work nicely:

```
FindMinimum[cost[θ, myX, myy], {θ, thetaInitial}, 
 Gradient -> grad[θ, myX, myy], Method -> "Newton"]
```

> {0.269, {[Theta] -> {-22.6096, 0.173579, 0.196086}}}

Comment: Thanks Alexey and George for pointing the way and thanks to belisarius, m_goldberg and Szabolcs for helping me to frame things to make it easier to get help.  Alexey correctly and comprehensively described the solution to my problem - there is absolutely no way I would have come to this solution on my own - thankyou.